# URL incorrect in Octopress on subdomain

Tags: blogging, jekyll

I followed the instructions to the best of my ability, as layed on on the [Octopress website](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/subdir/), but for whatever reason, things aren't correct.

When I followed the instructions, I expect my URLs to look something like this:
http://domain.com/blog/POST

Instead (aside from the root page), they look like this:
http://domain.com/blog/blog/POST

What mistake did I make?

I did the following:

```
rake set_root_dir[/blog]
vim _config.yml #url: http://domain.com/blog
vim Rakefile #document_root = "~/domain.com/blog"
```

Thanks!

*Note: I would have created an octopress tag, but lack sufficient reputation*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place the posts under /blog/date...

in _config.yml

I changed

```
permalink: /blog/:year/:month/:day/:title/
```

to

```
permalink: /:year/:month/:day/:title/
```

This change was in addition to the instructions from http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/subdir/

That worked for the blog posts themselves, but the archives page stills show up as /blog/blog/archives

You can probably search the source for "archives" to see how that's generated if you want to fix the archives page itself and the pages that link to it. Octopress is a blogging engine for hackers after all ;)